# Captcha not appearing in template

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a module and added a new frontend value to magento in order to display the Captcha on the product review page.

I've posted this into my `form.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

This is the node in my `captcha.xml`:

```
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="review_form">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>product_review</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

On the frontend I can verifyt that `mage/captcha.js` is loaded (when removing the XML, its not => I assume its working so far).

However, there is no captcha. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have forgotten to define **`form.additional.info`** in the layout file. It is hard to guess, which part you have missed.

You can follow below approach to apply captcha in the product review form:

> Create **`app/etc/modules/Stack_Reviewcaptcha.xml`** and put the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stack_Reviewcaptcha>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Stack_Reviewcaptcha>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> Next define module's configuration in the file **`app/code/local/Stack/Reviewcaptcha/etc/config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stack_Reviewcaptcha>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Stack_Reviewcaptcha>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post>
                    <observers>
                            <reviewcaptcha>
                                    <class>Stack_Reviewcaptcha_Model_Observer</class>
                                    <method>checkProductReview</method>
                            </reviewcaptcha>
                    </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post>
            <core_layout_block_create_after>
                    <observers>
                            <form_captcha>
                                    <class>Stack_Reviewcaptcha_Model_Observer</class>
                                    <method>insertCaptcha</method>
                            </form_captcha>
                    </observers>
            </core_layout_block_create_after>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <reviewcaptcha>
                    <file>reviewcaptcha.xml</file>
                </reviewcaptcha>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <captcha>
            <frontend>
                <areas>
                    <reviewform>
                        <label>Product Review Page</label>
                    </reviewform>
                </areas>
            </frontend>
        </captcha>
        <customer>
            <captcha>
                <always_for>
                    <reviewform>1</reviewform>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

Here we have defined two observer functions, one for inserting captcha and other for validating captcha.

Next, we will define the Observer.php file and write the functions we have defined above.

> Create file **`app/code/local/Stack/Reviewcaptcha/Model/Observer.php`** and write the following code:

```
<?php
class Stack_Reviewcaptcha_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkProductReview($observer){
        $productId = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $returnUrl =  Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array('id'=> $productId));
        $formId = 'reviewform';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId))){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl)->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function insertCaptcha($observer){
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Review_Block_Form){
            if (!$block->getChild('review_form_captcha')){
                $captcha = Mage::getBlockSingleton('captcha/captcha')->setFormId('reviewform')->setImageWidth(230)->setImageHeight(50);
                $block->setChild('review_form_captcha', $captcha);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
}
```

> Next, define the layout in **`app/design/frontend/[theme-package]/[theme]/layout/reviewcaptcha.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    <review_product_list>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>
</layout>
```

> Final step: In the **`app/design/frontend/[theme-package]/[theme]/template/review/form.phtml`**, add the following code just above the  tag:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form_captcha');?>
```

Refresh the cache and check.

Comment: Great answer! I added the observers code to my existing observer and changed the name of the Child (which was defined in the XML above...). Thanks!

Comment: Great to know that I could help :)